# Launching Explorer from WSL

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

`start .` is used to launch an explorer window from cmd.

When doing the same from wsl, I get

> $ start . start: Unable to connect to system bus: Failed to connect to
>   socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory

Is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Since Creators Update you can call Windows executables from WSL if you add the extension file. You can open the present folder like this.

`explorer.exe .`

If you still need start then you can create an alias

`alias start='cmd.exe /c start'`

then `start .` will work too.

Comment: `alias explorer='explorer.exe'` was helpful also in case I forget to add exe again.

Comment: I believe it is not limited to `/mnt/*` folders only any more. At least in WSL2.

Comment: The alias gives this error: `UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.` and opens explorer to `C:/Windows`

Comment: In latest Windows versions the one that works is `alias start='powershell.exe start'`

Answer (score 0):

You can call Windows executables from WSL but you should add the extension of the file too. also there is another problem that in wsl when you want to open a directory in the file explorer, you should use `explorer.exe \\home\\username\\projects\\` command because windows cannot understand linux standard path slashes. so, I made a wrapper to solve all of these problems. **[this](https://github.com/mahyar1284/wsl2-file-explorer-wrapper)** project is a wrapper between the Linux command-line and windows file-explorer that converts `/` to `\\`.

with this wrapper you can interact with the windows file-explorer exactly like the linux-native one. the below box exhibits the way you can open file explorer using [this](https://github.com/mahyar1284/wsl2-file-explorer-wrapper) wrapper.

```sh
explorer /home/
```

Comment: There is a built-in utility for that in WSL for Windows build 1803 called [wslpath](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows10v1803/). There is also a SO post on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53474575/how-to-translate-the-wslpath-home-user-to-windows-path)